# Use query params of parent route to refresh the model in subroute

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a route `main` which has a query param `search`.
I have subroutes `main.sub1`, `main.sub2`

Going to `/main/sub1?search=hello` or `/main/sub2?search=hello` sets the query param of the `main` route to `hello`. This part works fine.

Now I would like to be able to refresh the model of `main.sub1` when the query param `search` in route `main` changes, so I here is the code of the route `main.sub1`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    search: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    // here I can use params.search to fetch the model for this route
  }
}
```

I thought that since there is no `search` query param in the controller of `main.sub1` Ember would be smart enough to guess it has to use the one from `main`. But now, when I go to `/main/sub1` I have this error message:

> Assertion Failed: You're not allowed to have more than one controller property map to the same query param key, but both `main:search` and `main.sub1:search` map to `search`. You can fix this by mapping one of the controller properties to a different query param key via the `as` config option, e.g. `search: { as: 'other-search' }`

My guess is that Ember automatically creates a query param `search` in `main.sub1` which conflicts with the one from `main`, and does not even try to use the one from `main`.

How could I overcome this problem?

Simply put: how can I use an attribute of a parent route as a query param of a subroute?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just have the query params in the parent route? You'll still have access to it in the sub routes.

Comment: Does your 'main' model changes with the query parameters? If not you could move the parameters to your subroutes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

It is completely enough to use the queryParams of the "main" route.
You don't need to add any queryParams to the sub-routes.
The refreshModel setting belongs to the main-route and all child routes will refresh as well.

Also you can use for the sub-routes model:

`this.paramsFor(‘main’)`

See: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/refresh-model-when-the-queryparam-of-a-parent-route-changes/14903/2